# Why is this "invalid C++"

Tags: c++

I was reading intro on gtest and found this part confusing:

> **The compiler complains about "undefined references" to some static
>   const member variables, but I did define them in the class body.
>   What's wrong?**
>
> If your class has a static data member:
>
> ```
> // foo.h
> class Foo {
>   ...
>   static const int kBar = 100;
> };
> ```
>
> You also need to define it outside of the class body in foo.cc:
>
> ```
> const int Foo::kBar;  // No initializer here.
> ```
>
> Otherwise your code is **invalid C++**, and may break in unexpected
>   ways. In particular, using it in Google Test comparison assertions
>   (EXPECT_EQ, etc) will generate an "undefined reference" linker error.

Can somebody explain why defining a static const in in a class without defining it outside class body is illegal C++?

Comment: the apparent definition in the class body is not formally a *definition*, it's just a *declaration*. it suffices for using the value but not for using the object. the c++98 standard had issues here (in its ODR), about when something was "used", but it's mostly fixed in c++0x.

Comment: You need to forward declare static variables in your source file (.cpp) if there will be any references to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First things first, inside a class body is not a definition, it's a declaration. The declaration specifies the type and value of the constant, the definition reserves storage space. You might not need the storage space, for instance if you only use the value as a compile time constant. In this case your code is perfectly legal C++. But if you do something like pass the constant by reference, or make a pointer point to the constant then you are going to need the storage as well. In these cases you would get an 'undefined reference' error.

Comment: "The definition specifies the type and value of the constant, the definition reserves storage space. " typo?

Answer (score 3):

The standard basically states that even though you can give a value in the header, if the static variable is "used" you *must* still define it in the source file.

In this context "used" is generally understood to mean that some part of the program needs actual memory and/or an address of the variable.

Most likely the google test code takes the address of the variable at some point (or uses it in some other equivalent way).

Comment: Do certain compilers let you get away without doing it? I don't remember ever putting another declaration outside the class in a source file and I never got any errors (in MSVC++).

Comment: @Seth Carnegie: It all depends on whether you "use" the value or not. This bit me earlier today, interestingly. The code `struct test { static const int x = 10; }; void foo( int const & x ) { std::cout << x; } int main() { std::cout << test::x; foo( test::x ); }` shows two different usages of the static const. In the expression `cout << test::x`, overload resolution finds `ostream::operator<<( int )` as the best overload, and that only requires an rvalue, so having only the declaration with the initialization is fine. On the other hand, calling `foo` requires an lvalue (bind to a reference).

Comment: ... to bind the reference you need an lvalue, and that means that the static member is *used* according to the standard, and the fact that it is used means that the definition is required. If you think of it, the binding of the reference *requires* the location of the member, and that location needs the definition. On the rvalue case, the address is not needed, but only the *value*, and the compiler can inject the constant in place (i.e. in the example above, the compiler will substitute `test::x` with `10`)

Comment: @Seth Carnegie: Try outputting the address of a static const variable, and also msvc will complain.

Answer (score 2):

Roughly: In the class definition, `static const int kBar = 100;` tells the compiler "Foo will have a kBar constant (which I promise will always be 100)".  However, the compiler doesn't know where that variable is yet.  In the foo.cc file, the `const int Foo::kBar;` tells the compiler "alright, make kBar in this spot".  Otherwise, the linker goes looking for kBar, but can't find it anywhere.